# MVC 5 - Cannot route to the controller or its action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to access a controller I have created and call one of its action in debug but I am getting an error. I can access the home controller and its actions but when I route to /booking or /booking/booktable it gives me the following error. It seems like the location of the view is not found.

Can someone advice on how to fix this issue?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you use razor as view engine and razorgenerator to have compilation of views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error itself is quite explanatory. Make sure that you have a view with the name and in the location that the error message says.